# Laravel REST route doesn't function

Tags: php, laravel, satellizer

I am attempting to implement the Satellizer authentication system into my Angular app. I have experience with PHP and Laravel, so I decided to use that as my backend.

Right now I am attempting to mimic what they do in their example Laravel code. That can be found here: https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/server/php.

I have installed Xdebug on my server and have it successfully connecting with my PHPStorm. Here is what my `routes.php` looks like.

```
// OAuth, Login and Signup Routes.
Route::post('/api/auth/facebook', 'AuthController@facebook');
Route::post('/auth/twitter', 'AuthController@twitter');

Route::get('/auth/unlink/{provider}', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'AuthController@unlink']);

// API Routes.
Route::get('/api/me', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'UserController@getUser']);
Route::put('/api/me', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'UserController@updateUser']);

// Initialize Angular.js App Route.
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

On my sign in page, I have an authentication button for Facebook. After the Facebook popup appears, I have it calling back to my Laravel. In the JavaScript console it shows that it is attempting to contact the correct route. Heres what it prints.

```
POST http://localhost:8888/api/auth/facebook 404 (Not Found)
```

I have the following method inside AuthController.php.

```
   /**
     * Login with Facebook.
     */
    public function facebook(Request $request) {...}
```

The function is never hit. From the information printed in the console, it appears that it doesn't know it exists at all. Is there something I am doing wrong?

The route `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');` is hit upon every request, and it goes inside HomeController and hits the index method every time.

But